# nth-child does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When I add divs together with the objects that I use nth-child on, it seems to get buggy.

I'll appreciate any help with this.

```
<html>
<style>
.documents > a:nth-child(2) {
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>

<div class="documents">
    <!-- NO DIVS: WORKS FINE -->
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="documents">
    <div></div><!-- ONE DIV: STARTS WITH THE FIRST OBJECT -->
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="documents">
    <div></div><div></div><!-- TWO DIVS: DOES NOT WORK -->
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwrhU/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is not buggy behavior; there's simply been a common misunderstanding of how `:nth-child()` works.

When you add `div` elements to the beginning, the `a` that you're looking for no longer becomes the second child overall (which is what `:nth-child(2)` means). This is because when you add one `div`, that becomes the first child; in turn, the first `a` becomes the second child, and the second `a` becomes the third child. When you add a second `div`, that `div` becomes the second child and the `a` elements similarly get pushed forward another step, so `a:nth-child(2)` no longer matches anything.

If you're looking for the second `a` regardless of any other element types among its siblings, use `a:nth-of-type(2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

nth-child while counting takes all the child elements into account and styles only those elements which match the element selected.
On the other hand, nth-of-type, while counting takes only the child elements which
matches the element we are searching for.