# :nth-child strange behavior with h1 and p

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When using `p:nth-child(1)` in the following code, the first paragraph doesn't get selected:

```
p:nth-child(1) {
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

```
<h1>Unrelated</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Check this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/nufopube/3/)

But when remove a `h1` it works, see this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xocuvomo/2/)

Any idea why?

Comment: There is a difference in `nth-child()` and `nth-of-type()` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6R2dy/)

Comment: Reading the docs answers this question https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: possible duplicate of [nth-child does not work as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580149/nth-child-does-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: Ok, thanks to everybody, I din't know about `nth-of-type()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`p:nth-child(1)` is selecting the `p` element that is *also* the **first child of the parent element** (in this case `body`). There are no `p` elements that are also the first child of the parent element in this case; the first child of the parent element here is `h1`. What you want is `p:nth-of-type(1)` or, more directly, `p:first-of-type`.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `h1` is the first child in the body.

Use `nth-of-type(1)` instead, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `:nth-child()` it acts as another selector. It's saying literally, "Give me all elements that are a `p` that are the first child amongst all their siblings." And you don't have any `p` tags like that. Your first `p` tag is a second child.

Comment: I guess you mean `p:nth-child`. not just `:nth-child`