# Selecting a child of an even div child

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

I am trying to find a way to select a div inside of another div, but only of the even (or odd) divs.

I tried:

```
.foundoutmore {
    background: green;
}
.clickformore:nth-child(even) > .foundoutmore {
    background: red;
}
```

but unfortunately all the backgrounds are green. I've looked into parent and child divs but I haven't come across any parent divs that are children. (Confusing sentence).

**EDIT**

[jsfiddle.net/qgs30wrs](http://jsfiddle.net/qgs30wrs) fiddle here. Javascript is not my strong point, doing a cleanup afterwards when I can get it to look correctly.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Post a complete code example please, which here would mean your HTML as well as your CSS.

Comment: This looks fine when I put it into a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/y6j42hrn/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qgs30wrs/

Don't judge the javascript too much, I'm cleaning the whole lot up as soon as I can get it working.

Comment: FYI - your JS can be massively simplified (http://jsfiddle.net/qgs30wrs/4/)

Comment: Thanks @Moob, I understand it's awful, but I didn't want to concentrate on it if what I was trying to achieve wouldn't work. Thanks for the fiddle  though, will take this into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one `.clickformore` element in each parent element. `nth-child` looks for elements that are the nth-child *of their parent element*. That's why it's not working. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117284/2756409) for more info.

Use this code instead:

```
a:nth-child(even) .clickformore > .foundoutmore {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: This has worked! Thank you, also appreciate the link, I hadn't realised this about parents, so good to learn. Hopefully this'll help others too.

Comment: ':nth-child' is CSS3 in case you need crossbrowser support - check http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anth-child%28%29

Comment: @jan199674 "crossbrowser" should be "IE8" ;-)

Comment: Considering the OP *started* out with `:nth-child()`, they probably don't need it.

Comment: @BoltClock don't need what? The link?

Comment: Yeah. The most recent browser that does not fully support Selectors 3 (other than Safari/Chrome) came out six years ago and the standard itself has been a REC for over half that time - I think it's well long enough that only those maintaining legacy code needs this sort of information. And as I recently mentioned [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889164/can-i-use-css-to-apply-styles-based-on-child-element-count/27889205#comment44179319_27889205), there's Selectors 4 to worry about in the near future...

Comment: @BoltClock Ohhh, you were addressing jan199674. I thought you were addressing me with your comment.